# I need to add sections in xorg.conf, do I need to create it?

Tags: 11.10, xorg, ati, kms

I understand that 10.10 / KMS does not use `xorg.conf`; however, I need to add the following to my `xorg.conf` in a `Device` section:

```
Option "Capabilities" "0x00000800"
Option "UseFastTLS" "off"
Option "KernelModuleParm" "locked-userpages=0"
```

However, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` does not exist...  Do I have to recreate one, or do I have to add this to a file inside of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`?

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to build your own, 10.04 & newer releases do not have an Xorg.conf.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config

Answer (score 0):

Just do `gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, paste the section in, save it and it'll be created.